# Dynamically insert an article at the top of a taxonomy archive - or?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives

I'm making a directory for half a dozen sorts of venues that are located in innumerable cities in all 50 US states.  My plan has been to use a custom post type for each venue type and then assign a hierarchical "location" taxonomy to all of them.

When I create my "location" taxonomy archives, I'd like to start plugging in information about each state and eventually each major city.  I envision an article about the location, a list of related tags and categories about what could be found in that location, and some excerpts from blog posts.  Once you click through to a venue type, you'd get a list of that sort of venue in the "location."

How can I dynamically add an article about that location to the top of a location taxonomy's archives?

Or, should I have gone with a "location" custom post type instead?  However... that would still give me a location-related taxonomy archive that does not begin with an article about the location.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure off-hand if custom taxonomies have this (I'm almost positive they do) but Tags and Categories already have a Description field you can fill out, and then display on any page. It would take some modification of your template files but what you can do is something like this:

1. Enter the description in the appropriate field
2. Use this code to display it on `archive.php` or whatever controls your archive pages:

   ```
   $termdesc = term_description( $term_id, 'location' /* or taxonomy name */ );
   if( $termdesc != '' )
       echo $termdesc;
   ```

Code above is using [`term_description`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_description).

Comment: you're right, taxonomies can have an entry field for a description, just like blog tags and categories - a little tiny entry field.  I want to be able to insert more information, say a paragraph about the area's history plus a list of seasonal cultural events and a joke about the weather.  If it wasn't a big site I could hard code it.  

Is there a way to stop the description field from messing with my html?  If so, it would not matter that the field is tiny.  ;-).  

It would be neat if, instead of html, I could drop in a link into the description field and have it become an include.

Comment: The HTML in the description field may be escaped but in that case you could do something like: `echo html_entity_decode( $termdesc );` and it should render the HTML fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a taxonomy template and customize it with whatever you want.

The WordPress hierarchy for taxonomies flows like this.

> archive.php --->  taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php -->
>   taxonomy-$taxonomy.php  --> taxonomy.php

So you can make a template called `taxonomy-location.php`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: I already have a taxonomy named location.  When users go to an archive for a location, I want to be able to top that archive with an article about the location.

Comment: Also, I could have 500-1000 of these locations to write descriptions for.  Let's say I have 3,000 community theaters, restaurants and churches that are spread around in 500 locations, and I want each location's archive to have a description of whatever city or state it happens to be. I don't know how to dynamically tell taxonomy-location.php to load the appropriate article to put at the top of each location archive.  Is there a way?

Comment: Use `WP Query` with `term_description`

Answer (score 0):

You can use both location taxonomy and a location post-type. That way you can put much more information about the location e.g post-thumbnail or custom-fields and have it loaded on every location taxonomy query.

1. Register the location post-type e.g location-post
2. Add a location-post for every location-term you made
3. On the location-post add a custom-fields that relates to the location-term ID e.g 'location-term'(key) = '12'(value=the location-term ID).
4. If you already using taxonomy-location.php, you can use a get_post query with a meta_key parameter to call the location-post right before the loop.

Hope this help